# elasticsearch `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it` after using password auth

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am trying to connect to my elasticsearch instance using the python elasticsearch library:

```
es = Elasticsearch(HOST="https://elastic:password@3392047428db45a0b0e41659542.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io",PORT=9243)
es = Elasticsearch()
```

but I keep getting the error :

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000002BD624E6208>: Failed to establish a new connection: 
[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000002BD624E6208>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)
```

I also tried but am getting the same error:

```
es = Elasticsearch(['3392047428db45a0b0e41659542.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io'], http_auth=('elastic', 'password'))
```

if I GET the URL and enter the `username` and `password` manually, I'm able to connect.
Please help me understand what might be a possible reason for this error...Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you try http insted of https in https://elastic:password@

Comment: Already tried, does not seem to work.

Comment: es = Elasticsearch(["https://elastic:password@1659ac8a9542.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243"]) using the  RFC-1738 format worked somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch(['https://test-ced76a.es.us-centrdadsal1.gcp.cloud.es.io'],http_auth=('elastic', 'password'),scheme="https",port=9243)

es.indices.create(index='my-index')
```